# CouchDB size keep growing after deleting

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I want to reduce disk size of database by deleting the old metrics, i.e. which are elder than 3 hours. But what I'm currently see is that when I do delete & cleanup, the number of documents is reduced but size of db has increased.

So, after some time of this constant auto clean-up, I see that size of database increased very much, but number of documents remains constant -- because of deleting. To delete, I'm doing bulk_update of items to be deleted and then do compact & cleanup.

Where can I read how this mechanism actually works and how should I delete the data properly? Another words, how to keep the constant size of database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete a document in CouchDB, the document is only marked as deleted, but its content stays in the data base (this is due to the append-only design of CouchDB).

Last year I wrote a [blog post](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2015/04/20/how-to-finally-delete-documents-in-couchdb/) about this topic, laying out three different approaches how to solve this problem. Maybe one of them is suitable for you.

Comment: Thanks, I came across your article(by the way, great article!) right after posting this question: basically, I had the same idea how to do that, but it just sounds a bit hacky to me -- and it certainly not convenient to create new db, so decided to ask just for the case. But this is the cost of CouchDB advantages, I guess.. Anyway, thank you very much both for article and for this answer!